# Does adding scope in Rails increase query performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have heard from my teammates. They said adding scope in Rails model increases the query performance. I don't think so. It will just add a "and" case in query. How that will increase performance?

Comment: A scope is just a class method. In terms of performance yes you are correct it does not give any performance benefit if measured in time. But it does keep the code quite readable compared to not declaring the scope/method and using the query condition everywhere it is needed.

Comment: Please **show us some code**. A question like this, with no code sample to provide context, is very ambiguous and cannot be answered clearly.

Comment: Does executing the exact same code, refactored as a scope, increase performance? No. Does your teammate's suggestion improve *your* code's performance? Maybe. It depends what SQL (and other ruby code) was being executed before and after the change. And, regardless of performance, it may be advisable to use a scope to improve code quality.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it does not. Scopes are just a bit of syntactic sugar to make querying collections of objects easier.